# Date validation using custom annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, data-annotations

I am trying to validate a date using a custom annotation but I can't get it to work. Using the code below I just get a server error if I enter a non date and not my custom error

```
public class ValidDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public ValidDateAttribute()
    {
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DateTime dt;

        if (!DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out dt))
            return false;

        return true;

    }
}


[ValidDate(ErrorMessage = "Date is not valid")]
[Required]
public DateTime birthday { get; set; }
```

Is there an easier way to validate dates and if not is there something wrong with the above code?

Comment: "I just get a server error"...what error?

Comment: That the date is not valid.
The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: I would expect an error message to appear next to the input box, this just gives me an entire error page

Comment: Sorry I wrote that before you updated your comment. Deleted that now

Comment: Anyway that's an entity framework error. So either a) you aren't checking explicitly in your MVC action method that the modelstate is valid before proceeding, and/or b) you've specified a date outside the range allowed by SQL datetime

Comment: what is the type you defined  for column birthday in your database table?

Comment: Your attribute is pointless - the `DefaultModelBinder` already does that validation. The error in your comment is related to trying to save a value which is not in the range for sql type DATE (probably because the value is `01/01/0001`)

Comment: @user9405863 it is defined as datetime

Comment: @StephenMuecke So how do I get it to validate against an incorrect date?